# rsync command fails when called through system()

Tags: c, system, rsync

This is the command I'm using:

```
rsync --partial --timeout=60 --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa' /path/file user@host:/remote_path/
```

This works when I run it on the command line, but does not work when I use system() in my C program.

Correction: This call will not work after boot up, no matter how long the program runs. If the program is restarted it will work every time no matter how many times the program is run.

```
status = system("rsync --partial --timeout=60 --rsh='/usr/bin/ssh -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa' /path/file user@host:/remote_path/");
```

The return value from rsync is 12: Error in rsync protocol data stream.

Comment: Maybe you have a different working directory when you run your program that calls system() ?

Comment: Sorry, I used an absolute path, not a local one like I used in my example. I'll change that. (Changed show to used)

Comment: Similar problem here with php: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5352194/solved-php-rsync-with-exec-not-working

Comment: You should post the actual code where you call system().

Comment: Is this on Windows? Windows' system() argument parsing is broken and doesn't honour quotes properly, which can lead to endless problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was the environment variables. HOME was set to '/' on start up instead of '/user'. ssh was unable to locate the known_hosts file and therefor the auto-login failed, causing rsync to fail.